# Link object key with return value returned function

Tags: typescript

```js
// try trim string
export default function safeTrim(value: unknown): string | undefined {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value.trim();
  }
  return undefined;
}

// index and items used for array
type Validator<T extends object> = (item: T, index?: number, items?: T[]) => null | { [key in keyof T]: string[] };

export function emptyValidator<T extends object>(keyName: keyof T): Validator<T> {
  return (item) => {
    if (!safeTrim(item[keyName])) {
      // @ts-ignore
      const error: { [key in keyof T]: string[]} = { // line 18
          [keyName]: [`Field should not be empty`],
        };
        return error;
    }
    return null;
  };
}

// ======= examples usage ======== 

const testObject = {
    propThatReturnNull: 'some string',
    propThatReturnError1: '',
    propThatReturnError2: undefined,
    propThatReturnError3: null
} as const;

emptyValidator('propThatReturnNull')(testObject); // should return null
emptyValidator('propThatReturnError1')(testObject); // should return {propThatReturnError1: [`Field should not be empty`]}
emptyValidator('propThatReturnError2')(testObject); // should return {propThatReturnError2: [`Field should not be empty`]}
emptyValidator('propThatReturnError3')(testObject); // should return {propThatReturnError3: [`Field should not be empty`]}
```

On line 18 i get error  `Type '{ [x: string]: string[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key in keyof T]: string[]; }'`.

I expected that keyName type is "keyof T" instead of "string".

How do I mast link object key and returned object key type?

[example on ts playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/PTAEBcCcE8MhLAtqAzleA7A5gKAKYAeADgPaTigAmeAZgIYCuANhTQxgMbjwkap008AFQSIAFADc6TBngBcodgGsMJAO4YAlArQJsoAD6KM1GpjyVQAbxyhQ8GqDHhoRPCUdSZeUAF5-oADkuphYgZrWtnagkHjgDJB8XrIAdOjimgDcUQC+UbHxicam5pTZeTgg9iaEoHQm9uB4iCiKKBagNGR1kJB00DgubqAAatLwlHTgZAA8QqCETSatJABGAFZ4XAB8fk7wTYgKQgA01dQEAPwKGAyIq3iQZwfNKNegQgDaALoRvru3JhMQzWUCfJR4WCYUAQ6AeD7fHTobA-UA5bL4YhkVjsLg8PjNIguMZMCZTWbzRZ4ZagNabHZiWEAOToiHkMMh8KE2lG40m00gc12NjsBQSfDEL0Qf2FUTsDicAEIUAJhKJJYdwZCWWzfhERdE7FUAALgFAAWngWFUsTl0SqQlcPkCVjBBCReiwiNQyKwP0yaMC9laqgodBQKCtGDoqyYPmmECdQVdWqhfFhXO9IRR3wDOUCKTtRrAAEkFsQtk1LOAABZTDnQHXxpPwVoAIgzjiEbeqaDwdEs8Lb2awbaLoA4vDQC16ZAUKdh1QbmY9oR+OT2BsNhtTTe9nwABgAxeB4JiWFA1kjMSyh0APBaIInQA-fE7juzoj8xOLimeQMhskNPJDTFIpASYIC0XKHBKjAfwEICQhWSIONWgYFUsB8RDENAWDJwwacmjQAB5DZK03O0iAAoghDrcAACVf0SJlmCYBRghINkfU9QJ30NaiSFo+imMKDAAFFZ0gABGDi+Komi6KmUTxUkgDIAAJgUdgSgwCx+OiQThOU5iJKkgBmG42JwDdwwnKdwAxQliT5clIDEQIjKUxjTNYoFwmcPBSPIrgslAKpL2vc8fzE0AIPwJ8XNJfkyA8ryRNMtSyGkgLiPAMj6XAMKIqvG8Yr-Kx0pMsSspkhRDxPM8L1K6K7wfZyX2+PIOpJMkBTSxSMpqqSNNyoL8pCoqAxKqLLDAvhKsG6rVJG+rj1PaLIrKtqfA619usS6BepS9zPKWnzhvU8yxuCwrirALbovm6wqoularrWxrNpa28SAodrDv2oA)

Comment: *"I don't understand why keyName type of "string" instead "keyof T""* There's only one variable `keyName` in your code, and its type annotation is `keyof T` so that is its type. So it's not clear what you are trying to say by this.

Comment: @kaya3 I add an example to demonstrate  error on the TS playground

Comment: Could you modify your code to correspond to the playground and vice versa? Right now [this](//tsplay.dev/WK73MW) happens? Also, if the object type has multiple keys, what do you want to come out? `{a: 0, b: 1}` becomes `{a: string[], b: string[]}` according to your type transformation but that's not what your implementation is doing, is it? It will have at most one of those keys. I'd love to see a [mre] here that neatly focuses on a single problem like the fact that computed property keys like `{[k]: [""]}` are unexpectedly widened to type `{[x: string]: string[]}`.

Comment: Yeah, the more I look at this, the more I need to a [mre] with test cases where the validated object has multiple keys.  If you update this and want me to take another look, mention me via @jcalz and I'll check it out.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz i updated the question and example

Comment: This is example is close to something I can work with, and the answer is going to be an outstanding bug/limitation with TS at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948.  But note that you have no good inference site for `T`; if you pass in a `keyName` of `xyz` it will infer a value of type `{xyz: any}`, which is kind of not what you want.  If you manually specify `T` as a type with multiple keys, [the wrong thing will come out](https://tsplay.dev/W4y7Bw).  It might be better to just make it generic in the keys like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx6yXw).

Comment: If the above solution meets your needs I'll write up an answer with an explanation, especially the issue with ms/TS#13948 since that's the crux of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{ [key in keyof T]: string[] }` type is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and it can't be inferred automatically by TypeScript in the function implementation, so you have to type the return value explicitly:

```
export function emptyValidator<T extends object>(keyName: keyof T): Validator<T> {
  return (item) => {
    if (!safeTrim(item[keyName])) {
      return {
          [keyName]: [`Field should not be empty`],
        } as { [key in keyof T]: string[] };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```